# How to identify where IOPS on zpool is coming from?

Tags: disk, zfs, top, htop

I am running a zpool which seems to always carry a load of ~300M writes. I am having trouble identifying why the load is so high.

In the screenshot, i run `zpool iostat 30` and observed the load ~300M on average between all the sampling periods.

Below that i am running `htop` and sorting by DISK WRITE. I can confirm `htop` is picking up the total writes, as in the Write overview in the top portion, it is picking up a similar Write IOPS as the zpool, but when i look at a per process level, i dont see any load at all?

Confused on where the Writes IOPS is coming from?

[image: IOPS View]

Comment: Are there any mirrors or snapshot replication processes? If the device with the writes is an SMR spinning disk, I’ve seen situations on some home NASes where writes take a long period of time 